# Regex - Match a string between second occurance of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of text that looks something like this:

```
?q=search&something=that&this=example/
```

In that example, I need to grab `that` . I'm using the following regex below:

`var re = new RegExp("\&(.*?)\&");`

Which going `re[1]` is giving me:

`something=that` - but it needs to be only `that`

I tried:

`var re = new RegExp("\=(.*?)\&");`

But that gives me everything from the first equals sign, so:

`search&something=that`

Is the output when it just needs to be:

`that`

I need to target the second occurrences of 2 characters and grab what's in between them. How best do I go about this?

Comment: `/&something=([^&]+)/` PS: How come i dont see the question as edited when the string clearly changed? I even have the old one in my clipboard...

Comment: Why do you need regex if `that` has no particular rules.

Comment: @revo it gets changed dynamically and I need to grab it to remove it to insert the new dynamic rule. I'm trying to target it using regex.

Comment: So you should know where this dynamic thing happens. After `something`? is `something` fixed? or what

Comment: @Jan indeed, as the string is part of an url with parameters. Strictly speaking though, the question is about second appearance in a string formed as given, in which it wouldnt matter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/something=([^&]+)/
```

and take the first group, see the `JavaScript` example:

```js
let url = '?q=search&something=that&this=example/';
let regex = /something=([^&]+)/
let match = regex.exec(url);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` seems more suited to your case:

`"?q=search&something=that&this=example/".split("&")[1].split("=")[1]`

Then you could also implement a simple method to extract any wanted value :

```
function getValue(query, index) {
   const obj = query.split("&")[index];
   if(obj) obj.split("=")[1]
}

getValue("?q=search&something=that&this=example/", 1);
```